# blackberry unable to send url request to server continuously

Tags: url, blackberry

this is the code i wrote to send the url request using a thread:

```
   while(true)
       { 
         String url="http://192.168.1.7:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat=16.23&lon=21.998;interface=wifi";
         try{

             StreamConnection conn = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
             conn.openInputStream();
             Thread.sleep(30*1000); 
             conn.close();
            }catch(Exception e)
                 {
                  e.printStackTrace();   
                 }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         }
```

the code i used to this thread:

```
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    long time=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
   add(new RichTextField(String.valueOf(time)));

(new test()).start();
```

by using this code i am able to send one request successfully but after that server is not receiving other request. please provide me a solution.

Comment: But I don't see where do you close your opened connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when you're using a while loop like this, you shouldn't put the sleep within the try method.

```
 while(true)
   { 
    try{
        String url="http://192.19.18.10:8084/SFTS/updateLocation.jsp?empid=12304&lat="+lan+".23&lon=21.998;interface=wifi";
        StreamConnection conn = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        conn.openInputStream();;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
     }
```

Secondly, you're constantly trying to create a new stream without first closing the previous connection. Either read up on how StreamConnection works effectively, or simply use ConnectionFactory and not StreamConnection.

```
    ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(url);
    if (connDesc != null) {
                        try {
                            HttpConnection httpConn;
                            httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
                            httpConn.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
```

---

The above is for OS 5 and above, in your case... as the connection seems to work the first time, in your existing code I would try simply closing the connection using:

```
conn.close();
```

Comment: There is no ConnectionFactory in 4.6.0 version. I have blackberry 4.6.0 version

Comment: If your not using one of the latest versions, please remember to include which version you are using in your posts so others know about your restrictions.

Comment: Even then it's not working. See the code i've edited the result is same

Comment: If you're debugging, please can you provide the exception error.